# Is there any way to define a set element with an OR?

Tags: python, set

I need to check if subset A is a subset of B. Therefore, the easiest way would be:

```
A.issubset(B)
```

For A, I can have different definitions where each definition is a set made of strings, e.g. `A={"yellow", "red", "green", "blue"}`. However, there's one definition where I would like that one of the elements can be either one or another value, e.g., `A={"yellow" or "orange", "red", "green", "blue"}`. Therefore, when doing issubset, I would like to check if for the first element, any of both possible values are present, and if so, continue with the rest of A elements to look for.

Is there any pythagonic way that does not need to declare a second set?

Comment: *to check if for the first element* - is it always only the 1st item that is supposed to represent 2 items in OR relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
B = {"yellow", "red", "green", "blue", "black", "white"}
A_options = [{"yellow", "orange"}, {"red"}, {"green"}, {"blue"}]

is_special_subset = all(any(opt in B for opt in option) for option in A_options)

print(is_special_subset)
```